# What are Socket.connect's sourcePort/sourceAddress parameters

Tags: dart, sockets

While using sockets, I came across the parameters `sourcePort`/`sourceAddress` parameters on `Socket.connect`. But I do not know what they are used for.

The documentation only says:

> The argument [sourceAddress] can be used to specify the local address to bind when making the connection. The [sourceAddress] can either be a [String] or an [InternetAddress]. If a [String] is passed it must hold a numeric IP address.
>
> The [sourcePort] defines the local port to bind to. If [sourcePort] is not specified or zero, a port will be chosen.

But I am not sure what exactly this refers to.

After all, `Socket.connect` already has an address/port parameter. So I struggle to see why I would ever need to specify those parameters.

Comment: Usually, in fact almost always, you don't need to specify them. You only need to when you have some reason for a specific local address or port.

Comment: What would those reasons be though?

Comment: Uually when you have multiple NICs and the default routing won't get you through to the target.

Comment: Could that happen when using sockets to have two programs exchange with each other in the same machine? A small portion of the users of my project have complained about a connection issue, so I'm trying to figure out if this could be the cause.

Comment: The `sourceAddress` option to `connect()` method should certainly be avoided by everybody who doesn't know what it's for and exactly why they are using it. If you're trying to connect to `localhost` it certainly doesn't make sense to use it at all, and if it is used it won't work unless the local address is specified as the `localhost`.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why I'm asking this, as I don't want to specify a parameter when I don't know what it does. But one of my users was happy to help me debug the error, and when I tried on their machine to specify the parameter, the error seemed to have gone away. So if you're saying it doesn't make sense, then I'm a bit confused.

Comment: For more context, the error I'm facing is that when trying to connect to a localhost with a specific port, the client seems to fail with a "Connection refused <port>". But the `port` in the error is a different port than the one I'm trying to connect to somehow. And specifying `sourcePort` seemed to fix that. But that's black magic for me atm

Comment: All that is meaningless without the actual code and the actual error message and stack trace.